# Error: Entity 'Task' is not supported for semi join inner selects

Tags: apex, soql

I am not able to make this query work, I don't know how to use the WHERE NOT IN clause. Can anyone please help me with this?  I will appreciate any help. Thank you!

First approach:

```
 existingTasks = [Select Subject From Task Where WhatId IN :  existingServTaskLibrary  ];

 for(Service_Task_Library__c ta: [SELECT Id, Name  from 
   Service_Task_Library__c  WHERE Service__c IN : selectedServices  And 
   Subject__c NOT IN: existingTasks  Order by Service__c ASC]) 
   {
     .. do something

    }
```

Error first approach

> Invalid bind expression type of Task for column of type String

Second Approach

```
 for(Service_Task_Library__c ta: [SELECT Id, Name  from 
   Service_Task_Library__c  WHERE Service__c IN : selectedServices  And 
   Subject__c NOT IN (Select Subject From Task Where WhatId IN : existingServTaskLibrary) 
   Order by Service__c ASC]) 
   {
     .. do something

    }
```

Error for second approach:

> Error: Entity 'Task' is not supported for semi join inner selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake in First approach:
Here you are using existingTasks which i assume list of task. When you use this as Subject__c not in : existingTasks, Soql compiler thinks existingTasks as list of String but it is list of Task. So only you got the error.

Suggestion: 
After existingTasks query add this.

```
Set<string> subjectSet = new Set<string>();
for(Task t : existingTasks){
    subjectSet.add(t.Subject);
}
```

Use the new Set in for each loop as

```
Subject__c NOT IN: subjectSet
```

If you succeed in this, there won't be a need for second approach ;)

Comment: Vigneshwaran-g,  thank you so much! I used your approach and it works :) Have a great week.

Answer (score 3):

I think pulling out the Task part of the query won't affect the efficiency of your existing `for(...[Select])` statement.

I'd just query your subject list prior to the `for` loop:

```
Task[] tasks = [Select Subject From Task Where WhatId IN :existingServTaskLibrary];
```

Then you can just include this `tasks` variable in your `NOT IN` clause.

---

**EDIT**

Oh and yes, I didn't look at the first approach - and the fix suggested by Vigneshwaran G is correct - you need a list of ids, not a list of `sObjects`.

One improvement would be to enclose that query in a `Map` to extract the ids without a loop - ie:

```
Map<Id,Task> taskMap = new Map<Id,Task>([Your query here]);
Set<Id> taskSet = taskMap.keySet();
```

Or even faster:

```
Set<Id> taskSet = new Map<Id,Task>([Your query here]).keySet();
```