# Is there a way to go from Task -> Case?

Tags: soql, case, tasks, object, inner-join

I have a SOQL query that is returning records that should not be returned.

As a little backstory - To solve this, I added on a `IN` clause to the end of my query but I am getting *"Entity 'Task' is not supported for semi join inner selects"*. I found [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78038/error-entity-task-is-not-supported-for-semi-join-inner-selects) and attempted to loop through a list outside of the query and then use a binded variable but am getting the same results.

The main issue - I found this is because the WhatId on Task is returning the same value as the AccountId on Task. **I need the WhatId to be a lookup to Case.**

orderedTaskList1 is the ideal query but because WhatId is returning the AccountId AND I can't do semi join inner selects, I am not getting back the correct results.

I have to do a nested query because I need the CaseNumber field along with all the Task fields.

Is there a way to go from Task -> Case?

```
orderedTaskList1 = [SELECT (SELECT CreatedDate, Comments__c, OwnerId, Subject, Owner.Name, AccountId, WhatId, CreatedById, Account.Name FROM Tasks WHERE Private__c = FALSE AND (Status = 'Completed' OR Status = 'Closed') ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC), AccountId, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE AccountId = :strAccountId AND Id IN (SELECT WhatId FROM Task WHERE AccountId = :strAccountId)];

orderedTaskList2 = [SELECT (SELECT CreatedDate, Comments__c, OwnerId, Subject, Owner.Name, AccountId, WhatId, CreatedById, Account.Name FROM Tasks WHERE Private__c = FALSE AND (Status = 'Completed' OR Status = 'Closed') ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC), AccountId, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE AccountId = :strAccountId AND Id IN :accountIds];

for(Task task : [SELECT WhatId, AccountId FROM Task WHERE AccountId = :strAccountId]) {
    accountIds.add(task.WhatId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's special magic in SOQL, and it goes like this:

Code:

```
select id, whatid from task where what.type = 'Case'
```

Hope this helps...